# JSF Simple Login Screen - Three Incorrect Attempts Lockout

Tags: java, jsf

I am new to JSF and trying to create a login script in JSF. It successfully redirects to the loginsuccess and loginfailure. but when it comes for redirecting the user when the user has entered the password 3 times incorrectly, it does not redirects --> it gives me this error --> Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/index.xhtml' for action '#{login.checkLogin}' with outcome 'loginlocked'. I am using Netbeans 7.0 and unable to locate the faces-config.xml.

Index.html

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org 
   /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">


<head><title>JSF Login</title></head>
<body>
<h:form>
<table>
<tr>
<td><h:outputText value="Username: " /></td>
<td><h:inputText id="loginname" 
value="#{login.userName}" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><h:outputText value="Password: " /></td>
<td><h:inputSecret id="password" 
 value="#{login.password}" />
</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td> </td>
<td><h:commandButton value="Login" 
 action="#{login.checkLogin}"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<h:outputLabel value="#{login.label1}" />
</h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

loginBean.java

```
package login;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="login")
@RequestScoped
public class loginBean {
private String userName;
private String password;
private String label1;
private static int numOfAttempts = 0;
/** Creates a new instance of loginBean */
public loginBean() {
}

/**
 * @return the userName
 */
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

/**
 * @param userName the userName to set
 */
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

/**
 * @return the password
 */
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

/**
 * @param password the password to set
 */
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

/**
 * @return the label1
 */
public String getLabel1() {
    return label1;
}

/**
 * @param label1 the label1 to set
 */
public void setLabel1(String label1) {
    this.label1 = label1;
}

 public String checkLogin()
{

    if (userName.equals("Neetu") && password.equals("123456"))
    {
        this.setLabel1("Login Success");
        return "loginsuccess";
    }
    else
    {
        numOfAttempts++;
        if (numOfAttempts >= 3)
        {
        this.setLabel1("Account Locked");
        return "loginlocked";
        }
        else
        {
            this.setLabel1("Login Failure" + numOfAttempts);
             return "loginfailure";
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're relying on the new JSF 2.0 implicit navigation feature, then this error basically means that you don't have a `loginlocked.xhtml` file.

The `faces-config.xml` is normally in the webapp's `/WEB-INF` folder. But in JSF 2.0 you don't necessarily need it.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete question, there's a major design problem in your bean:

```
private static int numOfAttempts = 0;
```

A `static` field is shared among **all** instances of the class, applicationwide. If *one* visitor mistypes the password 3 times, then *every other visitor* is locked. Although, that will happen when you fix another bug in your code. You aren't in the `checkLogin()` method checking if the `numOfAttempts` has exceeded *before* you check the username/password. So, anyone who is locked out can still successfully login when the right username/password is been entered.

Work on your logical thinking and math skills :)